# Execute a Batch and Powershell Script on a Remote File Server

Tags: javascript, powershell, batch-file, samba

I'm telling you that I'm trying to figure out how to run a PowerShell script without having it stored on the computer. simply running it with some jse script and let the script know where the file is on some remote file server and execute it, i know this is possible cause i saw someone do it on a video but i cant seem to know how to.

The video I saw, the person in a .zip file had a .url file that when you opened it took you to a SAMBA server it was something like: file://189.000.00.1@80/file.jse

and a window opened where it asked you to confirm if you want to execute that jse file, when you press yes, in the background a batch and a powershell script are executed

I tried to open a samba server but i dont know how to configure it either or if the powershell and batch script has to be stored elsewhere and not in the smb server

Comment: Please explain your setup and needs in greater detail.

Comment: You can either copy the batch file or create the batch file using PowerShell to the local file system of the remote machine, then execute it via `invoke-command` using `-scriptblock {} -asjob`. Once the execution is complete, you can delete the copied of dynamically created batch script. It do this no problem on the time per one environments configurations. In case that helps you google some more things to try, then [edit] and let us know what you're having trouble with.